# How to concatenate 12000 files into 4 files based on first line?

Tags: linux, command-line, files, rhel

I have 12,000 files in a folder that have a similar naming convention because I used csplit on a larger file. I need to sort these files by the first line in the file, and concatenate the similar ones.

Each the first line of each file starts with either "> 1", "> 2", "> 3", or "> 4", thus I eventually need all of the "> 4" files to eventually be a single cohesive file (and I don't need to remove this > 4 header)

Example:

file xx1 xx3000 and xx449 look like this

```
> 4 speciesX1
ATGC
```

And I need it to eventually look like

```
> 4 speciesX1
ATGC
> 4 speciesX3000
ATGC
> 4 speciesX449
ATGC
```

Can anyone help me because I tried splitting the original file up with sed -n -e '/> 4/,/>/ p' big_file > speciesX.txt and it didn't print the chunks I wanted right.

Comment: Something like `grep -A 1 '^> 4' big_file`?

Comment: It will be simpler to split the original big file rather than keeping track of the 12000 files. Can you post a sample snapshot of the big file?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==1 && ! /^> 4/ {nextfile}1' * > speciesX.txt
```

This will skip to the next file if the first line of the current file doesn't start with `> 4`.  All other lines are printed to stdout.  stdout is redirected to `speciesX.txt` by the shell.

Note: the `1` at the end of the script *evaluates as true*, causing awk's default action (print the current line) to be executed.   It's a common `awk` idiom because awk scripts are essentially a series of `test-condition { action-if-true }` rules where either the test condition or the action can be omitted.  If there is no test condition, the action is always executed, and if there is no action, `print` is used by default.

---

It's easy enough to modify the above one-liner to match on `/^> 1/`, `/^> 2/`, etc and redirect to different files on each run but if you want to create output files for all of the input files at once, with just one run of the script, you could do something like this:

```bsh
awk 'FILENAME ~ /\.out$/ {nextfile};
     FNR==1 && ! /^> [0-9]/ {nextfile};
     FNR==1 {outfile=$2 ".out"};
     {print > outfile}' *.txt
```

First, this checks if the current input file ends with `.out`.  If it does, it skips to the next file. This isn't necessary if all your input files end with, e.g. `.txt` but I don't know if that's the case (you didn't say) and it's better to handle that situation appropriately.

It then checks the first line of each file and if it doesn't match an acceptable pattern (i.e. "starts with `>`, followed by a space, and then a digit") it skips to the next file.

Otherwise, ".out" is appended to the 2nd field of the first line in order to construct the output filename.

Every line of input is then printed to the output filename.   You end up with files `1.out`, `2.out`, `3.out`, `4.out`, etc.  You can rename them later with `mv`.

Note that `>` and `>>` redirection work a little differently in awk than they do in shell:

- Shell will erase & overwrite an existing file **every time `>` is used** (you have to use `>>` to append to a file).
- Awk will erase and overwrite a file **only the *first time* it sees that filename *within a single run of a script***, all subsequent output to the same filename (in the same run of a script) is appended.  `>>` prevents the erase and overwrite even for the first time a filename is seen by a script, i.e. it will always append.

BTW, the script's final line `{print > outfile}` is an example of an awk rule where there is an action without a test-condition.  This executes for every input line (unless a previous rule's action was something like `next` or `nextfile` to skip immediately to the next line or the next file).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IFS=$'\n' i=1; for header in $(egrep -m1 '> [0-9]' * -oh | sort | uniq); do grep -rl "$header" . | xargs -I{} cat {} >> file${i}; ((i++)); done
```

Run this command inside the directory containing the 12000 file, afterwards you will have separate files named file1, file2, file3, etc.., each containing all files with the same beginning of header ("> 1", "> 2") concatenate together.

Explanation:

```
egrep -m1 '> [0-9]' * -oh | sort | uniq - find all headers starting with "> number" ("> 1", "> 2") and remove duplicates.

IFS=$'\n' i=1; for header in $(...); do ...; done - iterate over the list of headers.

grep -rl "$header" . | xargs -I{} cat {} >> file${i}; ((i++)); - for each header concat all files started by the header to a separate file.
```